# Using grep -f to find the pattern themselves that have matches

Tags: bash, grep

I'm trying to give `grep` a pattern file (through `-f`) , but I want to learn which patterns are matching something in the search file

For example, given `1.txt`:

```
a/(.*)
b/(.*)
b/c/(.*)
b/foo/(.*)
d/(.*)
e/(.*)
```

and `2.txt`:

```
a/
a/foo/bar/
b/foo/
d/foo/
```

The patterns from `1.txt` that match something in `2.txt` are (omitting the `(.*)` suffix) are as follows:

```
a/
b/
b/foo/
d/
```

How can I "find the list of patterns that have a match"?

**EDIT:** I'm only looking for a prefix match but I think the question is interesting enough for general pattern matching.

---

**EDIT:** Since a `for`-loop based solution is given, I should say I'm not looking at calling grep 10000 times. :) The working solution I already have (listed below) is pretty slow:

```
for line in "${file1_arr[@]}"; do
  if ! grep -qE "^$v(.*)\$"; then
    echo "$line"
  fi
done
```

Ideally I'm looking for a single `grep` call or so with less overhead.

Comment: Do all of your patterns consist of fixed strings plus `(.*)`? (By the way, I don't think your "working solution" will work at all. I'm guessing you tweaked it between when you tried it and when you posted it here.)

Comment: Putting `(.*)$` at the end of all your patterns can I nly slow matching down. It has no impact on what is matched.

Comment: What output do you expect if more than one pattern matches a given line?

Comment: Are you sure `b/foo/(.*)` from 1.txt should match `b/foo` from 2.txt?

Comment: Finally, can you please specify what sorts of patterns you will be using and roughly how many there are. You examples suggest that they are all simple prefixe matches without regex operators; if that's true, there are some very efficient solutions.

Comment: @rici Prefix matching is sufficient. I am correcting `b/foo` to `b/foo/` now.

Comment: The general question probably is somewhat interesting but it's not going to be easy to construct an efficient solution. On the other hand, if you are just interested in knowing which of a set of prefixes is present in a file, there is a simple and fast algorithm, which essentially consists of sorting both the pattern (prefix) file and the data file and then (conceptually) merging them; any line from the prefix file which is a prefix of the next data file line is used. (Some care must be taken for prefixes which are prefixes of other prefixes.) But if you're only interested in...

Comment: the general solution, I'll leave it at that. (For a solution without regex operators but which allows the fixed strings to be anywhere in a line, you could start by creating a trie and then scanning each line against it. But I don't know of command-line tools to do that easily.)

Answer (score 2):

In awk:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=FNR;next}{for(i in a)if($0 ~ i)print i,$0}' 1.txt 2.txt
a/(.*) a/
a/(.*) a/foo/bar
b/(.*) b/foo
d/(.*) d/foo
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '                 # yes
NR==FNR {               # process first file
    a[$0]=FNR           # hash regex, store record number just in case
    next                # process next record
}
{                       # process second file
    for(i in a)         # loop every entry in 1.txt
        if($0 ~ i)      # if regex matches record 
            print i,$0} # print all matching regex and record
' 1.txt 2.txt
```

**Edit:** To output each regex just once (like shown [here](https://gist.github.com/ahmetb/0e73ebf167f3ff0491d422edcb0b32f8) in the expected output) you could `delete` the regex from `a` once it's been used, that way it won't get matched and outputed more than once:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR { a[$0]; next }
{
    for(i in a)
        if($0 ~ i) {
            print i
            delete a[i]      # deleted regex wont get matched again
        }
}' 1.txt 2.txt
vendor/cloud.google.com/go/compute/metadata/(.*)$
vendor/cloud.google.com/go/compute/(.*)$
vendor/cloud.google.com/go/(.*)$
vendor/cloud.google.com/(.*)$
vendor/github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/arm/dns/(.*)$
vendor/github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/arm/(.*)$
vendor/github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/(.*)$
vendor/github.com/Azure/(.*)$
vendor/github.com/(.*)$
```

**Also,** My test showed about 60 % off (mini laptop, 1:16 to 29 s) the time with this modification for GNU awk (using data you provided in the comments, `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`):

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FS="."                   # . splits the url
}
NR==FNR { a[$1][$0]; next }  # we index on the first part of url
{
    for(i in a[$1])          # search space decreased
        if($0 ~ i) {
            print i
            delete a[$1][i]
    }
}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

The speedup decreases the search space by using the start of the strings up to the first period as the key for the hash, ie:

```
FS="."                                           # split at first .
...
a[vendor/github][vendor/github.com/Azure/(.*)$]  # example of a hash
...
for(i in a[$1])                                  # search space decreased
```

Now it does not have to search the whole hash for a matching regex. More feasibe would probably be to use `FS="/" ; a[$1 FS $2]` but this was just a quick test.

Comment: Excellent answer. IMHO awk based solutions are ideal for heavy duty pattern matching problems.

Comment: @rici : please explain, your comment is too short :)

Comment: @rann The benchmark could be comparing the time needed  using the original solutiion, the excellent `awk` one  and my `sed` solution. And perhaps add, that `awk` not only performs well, but will also have easier to read/maintain than code full of backslashes, and can work better with code having special characters (in my solution I really hope that the input files dont have `#` or `\a` characters).

Comment: If there are really 10000 patterns, as suggested by OP, it's possible that awk is still faster than grep but it's by no means certain, which is why I suggested benchmarking. The ideal would be to check all the patterns in parallel, which would be straight forward if the patterns are limited to (mathematical) regular expressions, or even better, to fixed strings as appears to be the case in the example.

Comment: I do have a dir called `a_million_files` for testing but I don't feel like creating 10000 regex patterns. :D

Comment: This looks pretty cool! I actually need only `print i` (the pattern) only once. So need to `sort|uniq` this output. Is there a way to `break` when a pattern already has a match? I'm currently testing this. Files I'm using are at https://gist.github.com/ahmetb/ee6e6ee0c41c6d0d5f823309e85a0e1c. I'll be adding benchmarks.

Comment: So I added `break` inside the awk for loop (to print a pattern only once) and I get 23s in my input (vs 37s with grep). I think it's pretty good.

Comment: I have spotted a problem with this solution. If `b/(.*)` is in the list, it never prints more specific patterns like `b/foo/(.*)`. Here's a repro from my use case: https://gist.github.com/ahmetb/0e73ebf167f3ff0491d422edcb0b32f8 (note the `break` I added, I think the `break` is the culprit here, but without `break` it is much slower than calling `grep` everytime)

Comment: I realized I should use `continue` instead of `break`. But it slowed down to 1min35s (vs 37s with calling grep for each line). I think there is some optimization we're missing since files are sorted, and the pattern is always a prefix match.

Comment: About the expected output [here](https://gist.github.com/ahmetb/0e73ebf167f3ff0491d422edcb0b32f8); If you add a `break` (to exit from the `for` loop) and `2.txt` only has 3 records, your output can only be 3 records. 3 first matches, to be exact.

Comment: _Is there a way to `break` when a pattern already has a match_ Do you mean that a regex from `1.txt` would only be once (in which case you'd remove it with `delete a[i]` after the first match) or that for every record in `2.txt` only one regex will be outputed (add `next` after the `print i`)?

Comment: I basically need lines from `1.txt` appear only once in the output, if they match something in `2.txt`.

Comment: Updated the answer with `delete`.

Comment: ... and a speed-up for GNU awk (uses 2D arrays).

Answer (score 1):

The following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash                                                               

lines=$(wc -l < 1.txt)                                                          
for (( i=1; i<=$lines; i++ )); do                                               
    line=$(sed -n "$i"p 1.txt)                                                  
    line=$(sed "s/\/(.*)$//" <<< "$line")                                       
    grep -E "$line" 2.txt 1>/dev/null && echo "$line"                           
done
```

prints lines in `1.txt` that matched in `2.txt`:

```
a                                                                               
b                                                                               
b/foo                                                                           
d
```

comments:

```
# gets a single line from 1.txt
line=$(sed -n "$i"p 1.txt)                                                  

# removes trailing pattern /(.*) from $line variable
line=$(sed "s/\/(.*)$//" <<< "$line")

# if $line matches in 2.txt, print $line
grep -E "$line" 2.txt 1>/dev/null && echo "$line"
```

Comment: I already have this `for` loop. The problem is it's too slow, because it's invoking grep >10000 times in my case, which has process overhead. I'm ideally looking for a single grep command.

Comment: The solution I already have was: `for line in "${values[@]}"; do; if ! grep -qE "^$v(.*)\$"; then echo "$line"; fi; done` <-- But this is pretty slow.

Comment: You can include `-m1` option to speed up grep. But this doesn't solve the main problem, i.e. the multiple calls to grep.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the `awk` and `sed` based solutions, and I realized I can do this much faster using bash's builtin regexp engine if I read both files in memory.

Here's basically it.

```
text="$(cat 2.txt)"                   # read 2.txt

while read -r line; do                # for each 'line' from 1.txt
    re=[^\b]*${line}                  # prepend ^ or \b to the pattern
    if [[ "$text" =~ $re ]]; then     # match the pattern to 2.txt
        echo "${line}"                # if there's a match, print the pattern
    fi
done < <(cat "1.txt")
```

Since this doesn't spawn any extra processes and just does it in-memory, I suspect this is quite efficient. My benchmarks with the files I linked under James' answer shows 8-9 seconds for this.

Comment: With your question input this works fine. It works different with the regexp `f/(.*)g`. Your solution can match `f/` on one line and `g` on another. When that is what you want, you have found the only correct solution, otherwise check my updated answer.

Comment: This was really helpful, when I had to find out which of ~500000 patterns matched a specific line in a huge file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a solution with `grep`, but `sed` is an alternative to `awk`.
With `sed` I would like to see patterns like `b/foo/.*` in 1.txt, but I will show a solution based on the `(.*)`.
The purpose of the first command is constructing `sed` constructions, that will replace the inputline with the regular expression, when it matches the regular expression. The different output lines must look like

```
sed -rn 's#b/c/(.*)#b/c/#p' 2.txt
```

and this can be done with

```
# Use subprocess 
sed 's/\(.*\)\(([.][*])\)/s#\1\2#\1#p/' 1.txt
# resulting in
sed -rnf <(sed 's/\(.*\)\(([.][*])\)/s#\1\2#\1#p/' 1.txt) 2.txt| sort -u
```

The solution is a bit difficult to read, caused bij the layout of 1.txt, where I would want lines like `b/foo/.*`.

The above commands will have 2 bugs:

When the match is on a part of the line, the non-matched part will be shown in the output. This can be fixed with matching the garbage

```
# Use lines like 's#.*b/foo(.*)#b/foo#p'
sed -rnf <(sed 's/\(.*\)\(([.][*])\)/s#.*\1\2#\1#p/' 1.txt) 2.txt| sort -u
```

The second bug is that strings in `2.txt` that have two matches, will be matched only once (the first match will edit the line in the stream).
This can be fixed by adding some unique marker (I will use `\a`) for the matching lines and repeating the inputlines on the output (with `\n&`).
The output can be viewed by looking for the `\a` markers.

```
sed -rnf <(sed 's/\(.*\)\(([.][*])\)/s#.*\1\2#\\a\1\\n\&#p/' 1.txt) 2.txt| 
sed -rn '/\a/ s/.(.*)/\1/p' | sort -u
```

EDIT:
The work-around with a marker and restoring the original input is not needed when you follow a different approach.
In `sed` you can print something to stdout without changing the stream.
One possibility (slow for this situation) is using

```
sed '/something/ eecho "something" '
```

Another possibility is using the "x" command (that eXchanges the pattern space with the hold buffer). You actuallu want to have a `sed`script with commands like

```
\%a/% {h;s%.*%a/%p;x}
\%b/% {h;s%.*%b/%p;x}
\%b/c/% {h;s%.*%b/c/%p;x}
\%b/foo/% {h;s%.*%b/foo/%p;x}
\%d/% {h;s%.*%d/%p;x}
\%e/% {h;s%.*%e/%p;x}
```

Using above method the `sed` solution simplifies into

```
sed -nf <(
   sed 's#([.][*])##; s#.*#\\%&% {h;s%.*%&%p;x} #'  1.txt
   ) 2.txt | sort -u
```

When the file 1.txt is not changed often, you might want to preprocess that file.

```
sed 's#([.][*])##; s#.*#\\%&% {h;s%.*%&%p;x} #'  1.txt > /tmp/sed.in
sed -nf /tmp/sed.in 2.txt | sort -u
```